# Is possible to use replaceWith and replace in the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance

I'm using template engine, and passing a variable the only way I could , but the output of this variable that is an array that comes in the same line, without breaking.

```
<div>
  <h4>Questions</h4>
  <span id="question">
     How was your day?,Could you finish it?
  </span>
</div>
```

So this is how it looks, and I can't simply edit span text, if not looking at it after rendered, inside span my code is empty.

I want to do something like this:

```
$( "#question" ).replaceWith(  this.text().replace(/,/g, '<br>'));
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `replaceWith()`? This removes the `question` span so that the text will be directly in the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can either reference `#question` again to retrieve the text:

```js
$("#question").replaceWith($('#question').text().replace(/,/g, '<br>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h4>Questions</h4>
  <span id="question">
How was your day?,Could you finish it?
                            </span>
</div>
```

I'm somewhat doubtful this is what you want, because it'll completely destroy the `#question`:

```
<div>
  <h4>Questions</h4>
How was your day?<br>Could you finish it?                         
</div>
```

If you want to keep the `#question`, just change its contents, use `.html`, not `replaceWith`:

```js
const q = $("#question");
q.html(q.text().replace(/,/g, '<br>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h4>Questions</h4>
  <span id="question">
How was your day?,Could you finish it?
                            </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you say that it completely destroy the #question?
Because it worked, but only for the first file rendered.

Comment: See the HTML block in my answer -see how the `#question` is now gone? It's been completely replaced, which doesn't sound entirely like what one would want (but if you're OK with it, that's fine). Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML, so if you have multiple elements with the same ID, you should fix that first, then iterate over the elements of the new selector, whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback function for `this` to be set to the element that you're replacing.

Also, `this` is a DOM element, you need to wrap it in a jQuery object to use the `text()` method.

```js
$("#question").replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/,/g, '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h4>Questions</h4>
  <span id="question">
     How was your day?,Could you finish it?
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `html(function)` if you want to keep the span

```js
$("#question").html((i, curr) => curr.replace(/,/g, '<br>'));
```

```css
#question{ color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h4>Questions</h4>
  <span id="question">
How was your day?,Could you finish it?
  </span>
</div>
```